# Difference between POST Sanitation and Prepared statements in PHP

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement, sql-injection, sanitization

I always used the `PDO` prepared statements to prevent `SQL` injection.

```
$params = array(':param' => 'value');
```

But now someone told me that I should use `POST` sanitation to prevent `SQL` injection.

```
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Now my question is why do I need to use `POST` sanitation when I already use prepared statements for my queries?

So after all my queries could be not secure against `SQL` injection after all?

Comment: POST sanitation is not necessary involves PDO usage. E.g. user sends you his name and you output it to email template

Comment: For storage prepared queries 'should' be fine.  Later what will you be doing with the data?  You have to decide when and what to escape/filter appropriately.

Comment: The reason would primarily be if you want to do something else with the data (i.e. not just saving it to a database). Think of other aspects of your application (or other usage of the data) which could be vulnerable to various things, e.g. JavaScript injection attacks, that kind of thing). Other forms of sanitising can be useful for that. Find out what filter_input_array actually does, and then decide if you need it or not, rather than just using it because someone told you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Prepared statements protect you from SQL injection, but do not ensure data is valid.

But beside a possible SQL injection you want your data as valid and clean as possible.

Say, someone gives an email address in a form, but it isn't one, you should not store it before being validated. Same for any other data type.

Doing some things like trimming spaces makes data smaller. Smaller data benefits also by faster results and indexing.

The safest way to prevent SQL injections is using PDO and prepared statements.

You should also verify any input before inserted, because **user** data can be evil. Many forms are spammed by bots, for example.

Comment: Can you also explain when I need to use post sanitation?

Comment: Simple answer: always, because you can not trust any input - if you want security.

Comment: But isn't using PDO prepared statements not enough?

Comment: Prepared statements protects you from SQL injection, but does not ensure data is valid.